# String binary operations

Tags: python

I want to do OR operation on binaries. I have the binaries in strings.
E.g

```
>>> 110 | 001
111
```

I have these binaries as strings. LIke this:
'110100' and '001011'

For the above inputs, I want an output : 111111

Comment: This question isn't clear. Do you mean you have a string like this "110100" which you then split in half and do the following: `110 | 100`. Or do you want to do the operation on two separate binary numbers in two different strings.

Comment: @DanielWesleyPorteous I have inputs in strings. Two different inputs. Both are binaries like "101010" . Means, in string format. So how can we do any operation like AND, OR, or XOR . The basic problem is converting them into true binary before doing anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two strings with a binary number inside them, you can simply convert them to base 10 integers and then do your binary operations inside a bin().

```
num1 = int("110", 2)
num2 = int("001", 2)

print(bin(num1 | num2))
# Prints 0b111
```

Or for your second example:

```
num1 = int("110100", 2)
num2 = int("001011", 2)

print(bin(num1 | num2))
# Prints 0b111111
```

This gives you answers in actual binary numbers inside python. For reference, I recommend this question: [Binary numbers in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1523465/binary-numbers-in-python)

Comment: Nice answer. This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I could do what I want like this. May be there are simpler ideas.

```
>>> eval('0b' + '110100') | eval('0b' + '001011')
63

>>> bin(63)
'0b111111'
```