# Adding two nos. without any operator

Tags: c++, c

Is it possible to add two numbers without using any arithmetic or logical operators?

If so, how do I do it?

**Solution:**

```
main(){ 
  int x=10,y=21; 
  char *p=x; 
  printf("%d" , &p[y]); 
}
```

Atleast do not downvote this question as u didnt get the answer.

Comment: Is this out of personal interest, or something like an interview question? Anyways, I'm tired at the moment, and all I can think of is inline assembly.

Comment: i dont know...some1 asked me ..& i think its solution exists...but i dont know...wat it is

Comment: Sounds like homework or interview question ... if so, please tag it that way.

Comment: This type of questions has been posed many times. Please use the search tool before posting. Possible duplicate of [How to add two numbers without using ++ or + or another arithmetic operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149929/how-to-add-two-numbers-without-using-or-or-another-arithmetic-operator)

Comment: @JensGustedt Not a dupe. This one also forbids logical operators.

Comment: @Mysticial, I don't have the impression that the question is as precisely posed as you suggest. In the contrary, I don't think that he has looked much around before posing it.

Comment: guys .. wait..
this is valid question & for better answer dis1 ... i think i have searched everywhere but didn't got the answer for this one..
and it doesn't allow u to use logical operator as well

Comment: i got 1 more answer for this.. `main(){ int x=10,y=21; char *p=x; printf("%d" , &p[y]); }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
int add(int x, int y) {
    std::vector<int> v(x);
    std::vector<int> u(y);
    for(auto& n : u) {
        v.push_back(n);
    }
    return v.size();
}
```

Comment: I like it. Not very in-the-box.

Comment: Nice... never would've thought of this.

Comment: very unique ... can you please explain this !! i have no idea what is this :)

Comment: I preferred the version with the loop. Good enough to go on a t-shirt.

Comment: @wannabeApro It creates two vectors with sizes x and y respectively, and then inserts all elements from the second vector into the first. Returns the size of the first vector which has now exactly x+y elements.

Comment: i got 1 more answer for this..

`main(){
 int x=10,y=21;
 char *p=x;
 printf("%d" , &p[y]);
}`

Comment: @mSickCodes: That's not even well-formed.