# add two numbers without using operators

Tags: c, printf, addition

I was searching for how to add two numbers without using ('+'/'++') and went through 
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149929/how-to-add-two-numbers-without-using-or-or-another-arithmetic-operator). But, I also found this solution:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int add(int x, int y);

int add(int x, int y)
{
    return printf("%*c%*c",  x, ' ',  y, ' ');
}

int main()
{
    printf("Sum = %d", add(3, 4));
    return 0;
}
```

Can somebody explain what's happening in *add* function?

Comment: If you have a C99 implementation you can instead do: `return snprintf(NULL, 0, "%*c%*c", x, '#', y, '#');` and not mess up the output. Anyway, this method will never work with negative values!

Comment: Can you use other operators (e.g. - / *)?

Comment: This was asked on stackoverflow before, but I'm unable to find it. Does anyone remember this one?

Comment: No, I can't use any other operators.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to add two numbers without using ++ or + or another arithmetic operator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149929/how-to-add-two-numbers-without-using-or-or-another-arithmetic-operator)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
return printf("%*c%*c",  x, ' ',  y, ' ');
```

The `*` in the `printf` format means that the field width used to print the character is taken from an argument of `printf`, in this case, `x` and `y`. The return value of `printf` is the number of characters printed. So it's printing one `' '` with a field-width of `x`, and one with a field-width of `y`, makes `x + y` characters in total.

Comment: Then this means that first %*c takes first ' ' character to print it x times? Am i right?

Comment: Yes and no. In the case of `' '` that's what it does, but the correct description is that it pads whatever character it shall print with spaces to fill the required field-width.

Comment: And are these spaces padded before or after the character which is to be printed?

Comment: @Vaibhav Agarwal: Just put a `-` for example instead of space and see the printout. For me the padding is at the front.

Comment: Padding is usually added on the left, but with a `-` flag, the field is left-justified and the padding added on the right.

Answer (score 1):

Well what happens is this: the `*` before `c` tells `printf` that:

> The width is not specified in the format string, but as an additional
>   integer value argument preceding the argument that has to be
>   formatted.

Hence this means that the first space character will be printed with a width of `a` and the second one with a width of `b`. At the same time `printf` returns the number of characters printed, which is actually `a + b` characters.