# Addition and subtraction using increment and decrement operators. C++

Tags: c++, loops, for-loop, operators

I have been given a task to add and subtract two int variables WITHOUT using the built in operators (+ and -) and instead using the increment and decrement operators. How do I go about doing this?

```
    int add1;
    int add2; 
    int total;

    cout << "Please enter the 2 numbers you wish to add" << endl;
    cin >> add1;
    cin >> add2;

    //perform addition using increment operators

    return 0;
```

thanks for the help!

Comment: Take a look at operator overloading

Comment: Are you allowed to use loops?

Comment: Is it that you want to do `add1 + add2` without using `+`, using `++` instead?

Comment: @JoshEngelsma I don't think operator overloading has anything to do with this.

Comment: See also genial answer here: ["How to add two numbers without using ++ or + or another arithmetic operator"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1149929/how-to-add-two-numbers-without-using-or-or-another-arithmetic-operator)

Comment: @Andreas I am allowed to use loops

Comment: @crashmstr Exactly this

Comment: @crashmstr my bad, I misread the question as I was skimming through

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is obvious that you need to use either loops or recursive functions. For example

```
int add1;
int add2;
cout << "Please enter the 2 numbers you wish to add" << endl;
cin >> add1;
cin >> add2;

int sum = add1; 
for ( int i = 0; i < add2; i++ ) ++sum;

int diff = add1; 
for ( int i = 0; i < add2; i++ ) --diff;

std::cout << "sum is equal to: " << sum << std::endl;  
std::cout << "difference is equal to: " << diff << std::endl;  

return 0;
```

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense. For loops are still very new too me so I was confused

Answer (score 4):

Use a `for` loop.

e.g.

```
 for (; add1; add1--, add2++);
```

`add2` will be `add1 + add2` assuming add1 is positive

Similar idea for subtraction

Answer (score -1):

You have to use some sort of built in operators to perform this unless you are required to write a token parser and create your own interpreter and compiler. But I'm guessing since the question is quite basic, it's not asking you to do that.

You can simply do this:

```
int add1;
int add2;
cout << "Please enter the 2 numbers you wish to add" << endl;
cin >> add1;
cin >> add2;

//perform addition using increment operator
cout << (add1 += add2);

return 0;
```

EDIT - added decrement operator with less than or equal to 0 if/else:

```
int add1;
int add2;
int sub1;
int sub2;

cout << "Please enter the 2 numbers you wish to add" << endl;
cin >> add1;
cin >> add2;

//perform addition using increment operator
cout << (add1 += add2);

cout << "Please enter the 2 numbers you wish to subtract" << endl;
cin >> sub1;
cin >> sub2;

if((sub1 - sub2) <= 0)
{
    cout << "Number is less than or equal to 0." << endl;
}
else
    cout << (sub1 -= sub2);


return 0;
```

Comment: Remember, there's no reason to make it overly complicated. If you want to try a for loop to get this done then it's fine but, in my opinion, it's overdoing it for the task. As a programmer, not only is your job to solve problems, but to solve them in the best possible way.